# How to set fixed (8mm) linespacing?

Tags: memoir, line-spacing, setspace

My university wants me to have in my report line spacing of not less than 8mm. ( Font size must be 11pt or larger. )

How can I specify this other than using \lineskip which is discouraged?

I'd like to use memoir but even with setspace I could not find how to get this done.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Say `\linespread{2.37}` in the preamble.

The strut for 11pt font size is 9.52pt high, adding 8mm gives 32.28pt; dividing 32.28 by 13.6pt (the normal baseline skip), we get 2.37.

It goes without saying that the result is very poor from a typographical point of view.

If "line spacing" means the distance between consecutive baselines, then the computation is different: 8mm = 22.76219pt; dividing this by 13.6pt yields a factor 1.674:

```
\linespread{1.674}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `\fontsize {11pt}{8mm}\selectfont` work as well?

Comment: @Martin: This wouldn't set an enlarged line spacing also for other font sizes, particularly `\small` or `\footnotesize` (where it would be less than 8mm, to be honest, but this shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: It seems 2.37 is too high.@Martin: Could you publish your suggestion as an answer, please. That achieves what I _they_ want (I certainly don't).

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "linespacing"; if you mean the space between two consecutive baselines, the factor to use is 1.674

Comment: @egreg How can we know that "the strut for 11pt font size is 9.12pt high"? Is this for the default font style only, or different for different font styles for example Helvetica or Times? What about for different font sizes?

Comment: @Chang `\the\ht\strutbox` in a document with the `11pt` option. LaTeX doesn't take the font dimension into consideration.

Comment: @egreg It says `9.51996pt` instead of 9.12pt as in your answer?

Comment: @Chang Yeah, I don't remember how I got that figure. I guess a typo, because the other computations are correct, in particular 9.52pt+8mm=32.28pt (up to the second decimal digit).

Comment: @egreg I guess your old one might make sense. `\the\ht\strutbox` changes its value, when I change the line spaces. I guess `\ht\strutbox` includes some part of spaces in addition to the height of a line itself?

Comment: @Chang I'm inclined to think it was just a typo, because of the subsequent computations. Yes, `\strutbox` gets redefined at each font size changing command, including the initial implicit `\normalsize`, taking into account the current `\baselineskip` and `\baselinestretch`.